# How can I join a list of string into one string in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, join

I am trying to join a list of strings into one string using `.join()`method. However, it seems like the result is still the same where the output still producing a list of alphabet instead a word. Here's the relevent code:

```
import sys
import traceback
import weka.core.jvm as jvm
#import wekaexamples.helper as helper
from weka.core.converters import Loader
from weka.classifiers import Classifier


def main(args):
# load a dataset
 loader = Loader(classname="weka.core.converters.ArffLoader")
 train = loader.load_file("C:/Users/Syahirah/Desktop/Train_FYP.arff")
 train.class_index = train.num_attributes - 1
 test = loader.load_file("C:/Users/Syahirah/Desktop/Test_FYP_prediction.arff")
 test.class_is_last()

# classifier
 cls = Classifier(classname="weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes")
 cls.build_classifier(train)

# output predictions
#print("ID - actual - predicted ")
 for index, inst in enumerate(test):
    #print "\n", inst
    varinst = str(inst)
    #print type(varinst),varinst
    split_inst = varinst.split(',') 
    kata = split_inst[1]
    semua = ' '.join(kata)
    print semua
```

Here's the output:

```
T h e
c u s t o m e r s
a r e
a l l o w e d
t o
r e s e r v e
r o o m
o n l i n e
'
b y
t h e
w a y
t h e y
a b l e
t o
c h a n g e
o r
c a n c e l
t h e i r
r e s e r v a t i o n
```

Desired output should be like this:

```
The customers are allowed to reserve room online, by the way they able to 
change or cancel their reservation
```

Comment: What does your `test` variable contain? This isn't much to go on.

Comment: @Coldspeed instances variables

Comment: the `test` variable contain a list of objects with its variables. In this code, I extract out the second variable which is a `word`. From the list of words, I want to make it in a full form of a sentence. I am really sorry about m explanation. It is not well explained because I am really new to python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line at the first line of your .py file:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Next, change these lines:

```
semua = ' '.join(kata)
print semua
```

To:

```
semua = ''.join(kata)
print(semua, end='')
```

You want to make sure you're not adding spaces and newlines where not needed.